# Firemonkey TMemo OnChangeTracking strange behavior on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, tmemo

Does any one had same issue, then on run time created TMemo fires OnChangeTracking only then TMemo is empty (no lines) and only for the first entered symbol. And also then all text is deleted?

If TMemo is created in design time it works as it should.
This behavior is only on Android. iOs and Winows is ok.
Is it a Delphi bug, or maybe there is something I can fix? I use Delphi 10.3 Update 1 at the moment, don't know if problem ocurs on 10.3.3

Here goes a litle video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/NE4Gd9qkMVMKAnoe9

Comment: A number of issues like the one you're experiencing were resolved in 10.3.3. Is there some reason you have not updated?

Comment: Were was no reason to update :) It is inside use app, so the is no need for 64 bit. Will try to get update on next week. Curious if it will help.

Comment: Took some time, but I have updated to 10.3.3 and bug is still there.